# Asp.net MVC , CheckBoxs not binding in case of list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Though it seems like it has been discussed earlier also , but I could not find the solution -:

I have a VM like this-:

```
 public class RoomsVm
    {
        public RoomsVm()
        {


          Rooms.Add(new Room()
          {
              IsVip = true,Id = "1"

          }
          );
          Rooms.Add(new Room()
          {
              IsVip = false,
              Id = "2"
          }
          );  
        }

        public List<Room> Rooms=new List<Room>();
    }

    public class Room
    {
        public bool IsVip { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

    }
```

My controller has 2 simple actions-  1- for get and 2 for post-:

```
 public ActionResult IndexView2()
        {
            var roomVM = new RoomsVm();
            return View(roomVM);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult IndexView2(RoomsVm roomsVm)
        {

            return View(roomsVm);
        }
```

In my view - I simply display my rooms with check boxes like this-:

```
@model MVCApplication.Models.RoomsVm
<h2>IndexView2</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rooms.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem=>modelItem.Rooms[i].IsVip,new{value=Model.Rooms[i].Id})
}

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

}
```

Problem- When I click Submit button, I don't get updated values of rooms checkboxes in input value of  Post action ..

What wrong am I doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have accessors on your `Rooms` property

```
public class RoomsVm
{
  public RoomsVm()
  {
    Rooms = new List<Room>(); // Initialize rooms
    Rooms.Add(new Room() {.... //Add rooms
  }
  public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; } // Add get/set
}
```